# Useful browser plugins for openid authentication?

Tags: firefox, openid

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354/is-the-stackoverflow-login-situation-bearable and must agree to a certain point that openid (for me) makes it more difficult to log in. Not a show stoper but I'm used to opening the front page of the site, there's a small login form, firefox' password manager already filled in the correct values, submit, done. One click.
Here - and it's currently the only site with openid I use - the password/form manager doesn't even fill in my "login id". I often close all browser windows and all cookies are erased - and I would like to keep it this way.

Are there any firefox plugins you would recommend that make the login process easier? Maybe something that checks my status at myOpenId and performs the login if necessary.

Edit:
Unfortunately RichQ is right and I can't use Seatbelt. And Sxipper ...not quite what I had in mind ;) Anyway, both solutions would take away some of the "pain", so upvotes for both of you.

I've also tried the ssl certificate. But that only adds more steps. Hopefully I did something wrong and some of those steps can be eliminated:

- Click "login" at stackoverflow

  Click on the "select provider" Button.

  Click on MyOpenId

  Enter Username

  Click "Login" (Sxipper could reduce the previous 4 steps to a single mouseclick)

  MyOpenId login page is loaded

  Click "Sign in with an SSL certificate"

  Choose Certificate (grrr)

  Click "Login" (GRRR)

  Back to stackoverflow, finally.

What I really would like is:

- Click "login" at stackoverflow

  My (only) LoginId is filled in

  Click "Login"

  If necessary the certificate is chosen automagically, ssl login performed

  Back to stackoverflow without any further user interaction.

That would be more or less what I'm used to - and I'm a creature of habit :)

Answer (score 8):

VeriSign (ick)'s SeatBelt plugin: https://pip.verisignlabs.com/seatbelt.do

Ideally, the plugin would allow a higher-level of authentication. I know something like this was planned for the OLPC.

Comment: """To add other OpenID providers, enter the URL for your provider in the Add Provider field and click Add. Your provider must support the SeatBelt extension """

Unfortunately, not many OpenID providers actually support seatbelt, making it a bit of a damp squib...

Comment: myOpenID does support Seatbelt.  If your provider doesn't, ask them to!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Sxipper](http://www.sxipper.com). It provides intelligent automatic form-fill, including auto-login.

From the Sxipper FAQ:

> *How does Sxipper support OpenID?*
>   Sxipper remembers your OpenIDs and presents an overlay. You choose the one you want to use and login with one click. Sxipper also helps protect you against phishing.